# Search Files of a directory in another directory

Tags: command-line, batch-file, cmd

Things Required Step-By Step:

1. List all files/items in Directory/Sub-Directory.(e.g. List files/items of DirA)
2. Search All Listed Files in another Directory (e.g. Search files/items of DirA in DirB)
3. output the result using windows search. (e.g. each file/item is individually searched in DirB and results displayed in individual search Windows )

Required in a .bat file (Command Line script) or suggest a tool which helps me perform this.

Answer (score 0):

You can check for file and subfolder names from one folder in another folder like this (if that's what you mean by "search all listed files in another directory"):

```
for %%f in ("C:\folder1\*") do (
  if exist "C:\folder2\%%~nxf" echo %%~nxf exists in C:\folder2
)
```

It's not clear to me what you mean by "output the result using Windows Search", though.